# Did Neo4j Streams will try to send the data to kafka when kafka comes up from sever down?

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, confluent-platform

As i am working in neo4j and confluent kafka i have the following question.

These are the things i done in my neo4j.conf

```
kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
kafka.acks=1
kafka.num.partitions=1
kafka.retries=2
kafka.batch.size=16384
kafka.buffer.memory=33554432
kafka.reindex.batch.size=1000
kafka.session.timeout.ms=15000
kafka.connection.timeout.ms=10000
kafka.replication=1
kafka.linger.ms=1
kafka.client.id=testif23
kafka.topic.discovery.polling.interval=5000


streams.source.enabled=true
streams.sink.enabled=false
streams.source.topic.nodes.neo4jfailtest=neo4jfailtest{*}
streams.source.topic.nodes.neo4jfailtest1=neo4jfailtest1{*}
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.trigger.enabled=true
streams.procedures.enabled=true
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=streams.*,apoc.*
```

it is working fine and send the incoming data to the kafka topic correctly.

But for testing the data flow behavior from neo4j to kafka using neo4j streams i turn off the kafka server and tried to insert the data into the neo4j .

but when i make my kafka server up but the data inserted between the server stop and  start is not sending from neo4j.

is this is the default behavior or else am i doing anything wrong?

Did any one have a solution for this?

Comment: Well, you have `kafka.retries=2`, so after 2 retries, the producer will fail to send any data while the producer is unable to send to a unavailable Kafka cluster

Comment: so if  my kafka server is down for a whole day but when ever kafka came up i need to send all the data between the server down and up. so is there any recommended property to use for this scenario

Comment: Thank you so much @OneCricketeer,if i keep like this kafka.retries=99999 kafka.session.timeout.ms=1500000
kafka.connection.timeout.ms=1000000 will it work for that scenario

Comment: It might work, but it's better if you have a highly available Kafka cluster since multiple brokers failing at the same time is unlikely